# Django DRF: Default URL always gets trigered first instead of route.url

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple Django Rest Framework application, my `urls.py` looks like the following

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activity-list', activities.views.ArticleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Base/default URL, when all else fails
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

When I run the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/activity-list`, the route that comes from the DRF router never gets reached. The server always seems to give precedence to the default URL, and `index.html` is always rendered.

However, if I change the Default URL to:

```
# Base/default URL, when all else fails
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'BLABLABLA', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Only then are the DRF routes reachable. This is what makes me think it's a precedence issue. The DRF routes are working, they just always get beaten by the default URL.

I've tried variants suggested in the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routershttp://), without luck, such as :

Moreover, `/admin` works fine, which is why I suspect that it has to do with the DRF router in particular.

But the same thing keeps happening. How can I make my DRF routes reachable while maintaining a default route for the server to land on?

**Update:** So I've found that adding a trailing slash to the api URL causes it to work. This has led me to these two ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948659/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-in-my-url) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545741/django-catch-all-url-without-breaking-append-slash)) questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. According to the DRF docs:

> By default the URLs created by `SimpleRouter` are appended with a
>   trailing slash. This behavior can be modified by setting the
>   `trailing_slash` argument to `False` when instantiating the router. For
>   example:
>
> `router = SimpleRouter( trailing_slash = False )`

Having set this as the setting of the router and transformed my route to `r'activity-list'`, it now works with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: Yep. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to learn `url dispatcher` in django. Your default url's and DRF route's url's `pattern` is same, and default url is on top of the `urlpatterns` thus that url is getting triggered.

[How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Comment: How is it on top? I add it at the very bottom of the page and it's at the last index in the "urlpatterns" list

Comment: Did you go through the link I given?

Comment: if that was not helpful, we need your all `urls.py` files.