# Django catch-all URL that still works with APPEND_SLASH

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to route all unknown URLs to a single view.  However, in doing this my known URLs only work when they do not have a trailing slash, despite setting `APPEND_SLASH` to `True` in "settings.py".

Here is some code:

**settings.py:**

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
ADMIN_URL = "admin/"
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from myapp.views import my_catch_all_view

urlpatterns = [
  path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
  re_path(r"^.*", my_catch_all_view),
]
```

If I go to "localhost:8000", I correctly get routed to my catch-all view.

And if I go to "localhost:8000/foobar/", I correctly get routed to my catch-all view.

And if I go to "localhost:8000/admin/", I correctly get routed to the admin view.

*But*, if I go to "localhost:8000/admin", I *incorrectly* get routed to my catch-all view.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199446/1060339), but unfortunately that doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `r'^(?P<url>.*)$')`

Comment: @Tushortz - Thanks.  That has no effect.

Comment: How about `re_path(r"^.\/*", my_catch_all_view),` we catch it with `slash` at the end only. If it doesn't have `/` it will get redirected there?

Comment: *I have seen this answer, but unfortunately that doesn't work for me.* - what behavior do you see with that answer? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: There are a couple of other approaches you could consider - set [`handler404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) to your catch-all view (note this may not be suitable if you want a different 404 page for views that raise `Http404`). Or you might be able to subclass `CommonMiddleware` and call your catch-all view there.

Comment: @Alasdair - I don't know why it doesn't work.  The behavior I see with that answer is that "admin/" goes to the admin view and "admin" goes to my_catch_all_view.

Comment: @Alasdair - the `handler404` solution sounds promising.  If I can't figure out another way, I will use that.  Thanks.

Comment: If your catch-all regex is `r'^.*/$'` as in that answer, then `admin` shouldn't go to the catch all url. `admin` won't match the catch-all, so you should be redirected to `admin/`, which will be matched by the admin URL pattern before the catch-all.

Comment: @Alasdair - That no longer works for "localhost:8000" (no path).  I can get around that by adding `path("", my_catch_all_view)` to urlpatterns.  But that seems _icky_.

Comment: True, you would need need to handle the no path case if you used that answer. But that's a bit different from saying "it doesn't work for me" in your original question, or that it causes "admin" to redirect to my_catch_all_view in your comment.